# undefined reference to `CreateRGBABitmapImageReference'

Tags: c

I am trying to plot a graph in C and tested this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pbPlots.h"
#include "supportLib.h"

int main()
{

    double x[] = {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    double y[] = {-5, -4, -3, -2, 1, 0, 1, 2};

    RGBABitmapImageReference *imageRef = CreateRGBABitmapImageReference();

    DrawScatterPlot(imageRef, 600, 400, x, 8, y, 8);

    size_t length;
    double *pngData = ConvertToPNG(&length, imageRef->image);
    WriteToFile(pngData, length, "plot.png");
}
```

pbPlots.c/.h and supportLib.c/.h are in the same folder with my C file.

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

When I try to run i get this output:

undefined reference to `CreateRGBABitmapImageReference`

undefined reference to `DrawScatterPlot`

undefined reference to `ConvertToPNG`

After searching for a while I still cant figure out how to solve this.

Comment: Do pbPlots.c and supportLib.c define the functions with undefined references? How do you compile/link the program?

Comment: I build and run it from my CodeBlocks IDE

Comment: You need  the library with the plot functions. CodeBlocks is only the IDE.

Comment: I need to add it from Settings->Compiler->Linker Settings and link the library?